# Play video in view controller

Tags: ios, swift

FYI, I am using this Github Player: https://github.com/piemonte/Player

I am trying to play a video, but it wont work. On the View Controller's `UIView` i use background color blue, and when I run this project, I only see a bue background without a player. This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Player
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, PlayerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var myView: UIView!

    private var player: Player!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let fileUrl = NSURL(string: "https://parseapi.back4app.com/files/SAQY2fBCiob9UMqITqAEMo7UxNsU6MCCUURf53Ee/d349a0bdd0962cb0f570c95621aee6df_video.mp4")

        self.player = Player()
        self.player.delegate = self
        player.view.frame.size.width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        player.view.frame.size.height = player.view.frame.size.width

        player.fillMode = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        player.view.sizeToFit()
        myView.addSubview(player.view)

        let videoUrl: NSURL = fileUrl!
        self.player.setUrl(videoUrl)
        self.player.playFromBeginning()

        self.player.playbackLoops = true

        let tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTapGestureRecognizer:")
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        self.player.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: PlayerDelegate Start

    func handleTapGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        switch (self.player.playbackState.rawValue) {
        case PlaybackState.Stopped.rawValue:
            self.player.playFromBeginning()
        case PlaybackState.Paused.rawValue:
            self.player.playFromCurrentTime()
        case PlaybackState.Playing.rawValue:
            self.player.pause()
        case PlaybackState.Failed.rawValue:
            self.player.pause()
        default:
            self.player.pause()
        }
    }

    func playerReady(player: Player) {
    }

    func playerPlaybackStateDidChange(player: Player) {
    }

    func playerBufferingStateDidChange(player: Player) {
    }

    func playerPlaybackWillStartFromBeginning(player: Player) {
    }

    func playerPlaybackDidEnd(player: Player) {
    }

    /* override func awakeFromNib() {

     self.collectionView.autoresizesSubviews = true
     self.collectionView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
     self.collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
     }*/

    // MARK: PlayerDelegate Stop
}
```

**Attempt nr 2:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let fileUrl = NSURL(string: "https://parseapi.back4app.com/files/SAQY2fBCiob9UMqITqAEMo7UxNsU6MCCUURf53Ee/d349a0bdd0962cb0f570c95621aee6df_video.mp4")

        self.player = Player()
        self.player.delegate = self
        self.player.view.frame = self.view.bounds

        self.addChildViewController(self.player)
        self.view.addSubview(self.player.view)
        self.player.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        let videoUrl: NSURL = fileUrl!
        self.player.setUrl(videoUrl)
        self.player.playFromBeginning()

        self.player.playbackLoops = true

        let tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTapGestureRecognizer:")
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        self.player.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }
```

When I try to open the link in Safari, it doesn't work, but in Chrome it works fine.. Any suggestions what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the player is not actually added to your view yet.

Please follow this to add this on your view as a sub-viewcontroller.

```
 self.player = Player()
 self.player.delegate = self
 self.player.view.frame = self.view.bounds

 self.addChildViewController(self.player)
 self.view.addSubview(self.player.view)
 self.player.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Comment: Something is wrong when uploading the file.. I don't understand.. When using another `.mp4` file it works fine.